# how to pair JBL bluetooth device with Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio, a2dp

I'm using 14.04 xubuntu version and want to pair it with the bluetooth JBL Flip 4 speaker. If I turn on the bluetooth on the laptop and "setup new device" choose "JBL Flip 4", "Connect to..." A2DP Sink (Send Audio)" I get the anser "Device added successfully, but failed to connect". Does anybody know how to solve this problem, how to pair and connect successfully?

Comment: There's no "4.10 xubuntu". Please [edit] and correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Desktop OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Speaker: JBL Flip 4

I couldn't connect JBL to the notebook via Bluetooth.
The message was

```
a2dp-source profile connect failed for Protocol not available.
```

I solved this problem simply installing `pulseaudio-bluetooth` and restarting `PulseAudio`.
Maybe this info helps someone to save his/her time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution (for me) turned out to be very simple. Even when you were able to connect the device, you still have to go to the sound settings. (you can find this at the speaker-icon in the right upper corner) Here you still have to select the output; play sound through: in your case "speaker JBL". standard the "speakers built in audio" will be selected".

This is what solved the problem for me. I hope this will help you too.
Regards,
Nick